# Camera2 understanding the capture session's outputs quality decision process

Tags: android, android-camera2

I'm writing an app that should have two output surfaces, one for the preview and one for some YUV processing. For the processing, I want to obtain the images with the least additional preprocessing, knowing that most of the time there will be a 4x zoom. I've therefore chosen to select from the list of output sizes(`getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.YUV_420_888)`) the `Size` that is as close to a 4x zoom (`CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_INFO_ACTIVE_ARRAY_SIZE` divided by 4) as possible in the smallest sensor dimension. This way, I can apply the "*zoom*" (`CaptureRequest.SCALER_CROP_REGION`) using this `Size` knowing that the output will not be subject to (additional) interpolation.
The preview size is chosen based on the aspect ratio of the processing output.

My issue is that I have discovered that the quality of the output is highly dependent on the output surfaces that are provided in the `createCaptureSession (List<Surface> outputs, CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback callback, Handler handler)` method. I noticed this when comparing the preview images from the built-in camera app (at the same zoom) and the images of my processing stream(and preview). My repeating request is base on a `CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW`, so I assumed that I would get the same quality.

The docs don't mention anything about quality, they only speak of the possible streams and targets combinations and mention that the pipelines have to be set up.

> While any of the sizes from getOutputSizes(int) can be used when a single output stream is configured, a given camera device may not be able to support all combination of sizes, formats, and targets when multiple outputs are configured at once.

and

> Creating a session is an expensive operation and can take several hundred milliseconds, since it requires configuring the camera device's internal pipelines and allocating memory buffers for sending images to the desired targets.

I've basically discovered that if I add a dummy surface to my session (only used to initialise it) with a maximum output size (e.g JPEG:MAXIMUM), then the quality of my processing images is much better.

Although the stream configurations allows it and my special context (4x zoom) fits with the PREVIEW max size, I don't feel comfortable with this way of doing.

> LEGACY-level guaranteed configurations
>
> PRIV:PREVIEW | YUV:PREVIEW | JPEG:MAXIMUM  |  Still capture plus in-app processing.

So does anyone know what is happening, how the quality is determined and how to get a predictable output?

---

- Phone used: HUAWEI Mate 9
- sensor active array size: 3968x2976
- crop size: 1536x863

Comment: "I've basically discovered that if I add a dummy surface to my session (only used to initialise it) with a maximum output size (e.g JPEG:MAXIMUM), then the quality of my processing images is much better." could you elaborate on this? you mean that you created a new request with a jpeg image reader?

Comment: @TiagoSantos I created an ImageReader (`ImageReader.newInstance(largestJpeg.getWidth(),                                            largestJpeg.getHeight(), ImageFormat.JPEG, 5)`) which does nothing and added its surface to the list of surfaces when creating my capture session.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logic behind the scenes is complex and device-specific, so I can generally offer only some guidelines:

1. If the maximum resolution you request for your session is well below the maximum resolution supported by the camera, the camera will often try to select a more power-efficient mode to operate in - basically, read only a subsampled image off the sensor, instead of a full resolution one.  This saves a lot of power, which is important in video chat apps, video recording, and similar long-running tasks that don't need full resolution.
2. If the camera device selects a subsampled sensor mode, the quality of digital zoom will suffer substantially. Unfortunately, there's no way to tell the camera that you're going to request max digital zoom along with your low-res output to get a windowed 1:1 slice of the sensor.
3. So as a practical matter, if you really want 1:1 image quality for your crop region, and you're not drawing it to screen, you probably are best off taking a full-res image and cropping yourself.  Or if you need to display preview, configuring a full-res JPEG output (for example) that you never use, to force the camera to select a full-size sensor output mode.
4. Exposing more detail about sensor mode configuration is tough, because the restrictions on available sensor modes and various bandwidth/power limits are hard to describe in a simple fashion, so right now the guarantee is just that you get the pixels you asked for in stream configuration - there's really no guarantee that digital zoom gives the same quality no matter what, if you don't have a full-res output configured.

Comment: Understood, I'll be using a dummy full-res output from now on.